# Frontend frameworks vs Backend frameworks

Tags: reactjs, django, web, frontend, backend

As someone just started in web development, I was constantly bothered with these terms and really hoping someone could explain some of my questions for me.

What is the major difference and similarities between frontend frameworks and backend frameworks?

Can I use both in one web project or does they conflict? (Never seen a project that use both front and backend framework).

If one project only need one framework, then why are some named frontend frameworks some named backend frameworks.

Currently I'm more familiar with Django, a backend framework and in Django, and In Django development, frontend becomes basic html and css, though I was expecting something fancier (something like react components)

Never used a frontend framework in project or work. So how does backend stuff work in a frontend framework project?

Any answers would be helpful

Comment: Django when used with templating engine can deliver both backend and frontend. But you can separate the frontend part to some frontend framework say reactjs. With that you can have your backend in django rest framework.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use both a frontend and a backend framework on the same project.

Some backend frameworks, such as Adonis.js, Django or Spring, offers you a template engine (I believe this is the one you are using with django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/) which can be great for simple pages. But as you said, some times you need more complex features, in this case a frontend framework would come in hand (such as React.js or Vue.js).

In this last case, you could have two separate code bases that change information through an api. In my experience I always prefer to have a frontend separated from the backend, this way its easier to maintain the codes and you can use the same backend from multiple clients, lets say and website and a mobile app.

Comment: First of all, thx for the answer. I have a follow up question. So in larger projects, where you have frontend single page application built with react. and have django for backend. What does django mainly do? retrieve data from database? Or there is other things that django takes care of

Comment: I think its easier if we think as backend and frontend, not django and react, since we can use many tools to build them.
With that said, they have different resposabilities. 
The frontend is the part that interacts with the user so through the frontend the user will see and input information. However, in general the frontend should deal with logic aspects, thats maily because the frontend can be easily exploited by the user. 
Thats where the backend comes to action, its on the backend that we should deal with "logic" part of the business, a good example its retrieving data from a database

Comment: Another example is to retrieve data from an external service, lets say some google api. In this scenario your frontend would send a http request to the backend, then the latter need to process the request and collect the data requested by the front. In our example the data would come from an external api (google api). After the backend finished processing the data it will return it to the front, that will parse and display the information to the user

Comment: This is just one example, but we can have many possible situations. Another example would be a real time service with multiple users, lets say an online game. The server (backend) is responsible to collect data from all the clients (frontend) validate it and send to the other clients

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with Pedro - you can use frontend and backend frameworks when building the same software / app / website.
If you want to build a complex project, I think Vue.js will be a perfect choice. However, recently I have noticed an increased interest in developing digital products with React Native. To be completely honest, I don't have much experience with this framework, so I can't tell you whether it's a good choice. If you would like to check the best development frameworks, this piece of content will tell you everything you need to know: https://www.miquido.com/blog/the-best-frontend-development-frameworks/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can both frontend framework and backend framework at the same site.
the benifit of using backend framework includes Security, uniqueness, scalability and the benifit for using frontend framework includequicker prototype, standardized, more efficient and reliable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).